# Why is this cipher puzzle question so poorly received? (bmf kgf dc yufy ckd yb crysn)

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Question: [bmf kgf dc yufy ckd yb crysn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/126039/bmf-kgf-dc-yufy-ckd-yb-crysn)

---

This question currently sits at [+5/-4] at the time of posting. (+46 rep. awarded)

---

Overview of the puzzle: Friend gave OP (@theooofsof2023) a cipher and some clues on how to decode it, although the OP has no idea how to decode it, nor knows where they should go to decode it.

In my answer explaining why it was unsolvable in its current state, I gave OP the benefit of the doubt saying that most likely the clues and ciphertext were both transcribed correctly.

I am unsure about why this was overall so poorly received, because while it was a bit underclued, it is a good (if not first) attempt at creating a cipher puzzle IMHO.

It's kind of how my first puzzle "https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122666/a-simple-and-quite-fun-cipher-puzzle" was also a good first attempt at creating a puzzle involving a cipher. (Currently sits at [+5/-3], was also underclued and the intended answer was only recently revealed in a follow-up 5 months later)

So my question is: Why was this so poorly received? I genuinely believe that this could have been solved if OP's friend had given a few more clues (kind of like my first cipher puzzle), and I think that it was a good puzzle overall.